# React Material UI randomize/remove MUI class names

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to randomize names or remove Mui-classNames?

[image]

Like in the image above? (All CSS class names would be **jss**XXX) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

classNames like `jssXXX` are a result of uglification and will be auto generated by Material UI when the project is built for production mode. e.g. when you run `npm run build` in case of an app created using *create-react-app*.

className should be created in following way for Material UI to process it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, Theme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const CustomMuiTheme = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  label: {
    color: red,
  }
});
const theme = CustomMuiTheme();

export const CssClassDemo = () => {
  return (
    <label className={theme.label}>label text</label>
  );
}
```

Classes created by user only will be uglified. Classes such as *MuiGrid-container* which are provided by Material UI won't be minified as it gives developers an opportunity to customise these styles.